# using sed to find a match in a file and replace it with the content of other file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a content file something like this:

content.json (array of objects)

```
[
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
]
```

There is a config file which has similar content but diffrent value.

config.json (object value)

```
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
```

My target is to append the content of config.json file to content.json file, so that the new content.json file will become:

```
[
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
]
```

My idea is to find `},\n]` regex from content.json file and replace it with the content of config.json file. Since I am running these command remotely, my idea is to run it as single command using sed. But somehow I am not getting any proper documentation/ help in sed to achieve this.

Can anyone please help here.

Comment: Does each element of the array end with a comma, even the last one? If the last element in the array ends with a comma, it's not valid JSON.

Comment: its actually a javascript json and there such variables are considered valid json file.

Comment: ...also crossposted here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250600/using-sed-to-find-a-match-in-a-file-and-replace-it-with-the-content-of-other-fil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the files are valid JSON files, i.e. that the `content.json` file looks like

```
[
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
]
```

or like

```
{ "interval": 1, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
{ "interval": 2, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
```

and that `config.json` looks like

```
[
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]},
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
]
```

or like

```
{ "interval": 3, "expired": 3, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
{ "interval": 4, "expired": 4, "ignored": [ ".git", ".p4" ]}
```

... then `jq` can be used to easily merge the two arrays into the JSON structure that you require:

```
$ jq -s flatten content.json config.json
[
  {
    "interval": 1,
    "expired": 3,
    "ignored": [
      ".git",
      ".p4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "interval": 2,
    "expired": 4,
    "ignored": [
      ".git",
      ".p4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "interval": 3,
    "expired": 3,
    "ignored": [
      ".git",
      ".p4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "interval": 4,
    "expired": 4,
    "ignored": [
      ".git",
      ".p4"
    ]
  }
]
```

The `flatten` command in `jq` merges the top-level entries of an array.  The array is an array consisting of the data from each file as two separate array entries.

Use `jq -c` to get more compact output:

```
$ jq -cs flatten content.json config.json
[{"interval":1,"expired":3,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]},{"interval":2,"expired":4,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]},{"interval":3,"expired":3,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]},{"interval":4,"expired":4,"ignored":[".git",".p4"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it with `jq` (see other answer).

However, if you really have to use sed, and if the config file doesn't have the beginning and ending square brackets, like shown, then (with GNU `sed`):

```
sed -i -e '$rconfig.json' -e '$a]' -e '$d' content.json
```